# Matrices off the page

Tags: matrices

My matrix goes off the page. Usually, when I work with simple equations, I use the code `\begin{eqnarray}\end{eqnarray*}` to align equations vertically by the equal sign.

[image]

Do you know if I can do something similar with the following matrix code? `\begin{eqnarray}\end{eqnarray*}` doesn't work here.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

 %PROBLEM 2
  Let $\textbf{a}' = \begin{bmatrix}
       3 & 6 &-3 & 5 &  9& 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix}$. Find \textbf{a}$'$\textbf{a} and \textbf{aa}$'$.


 \textbf{a}$'$ is the transpose of $\textbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix}
       3 \\ 6 \\-3 \\ 5 \\  9\\ 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix}$

 \[\textbf{a}'\textbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix}
       3 & 6 &-3 & 5 &  9& 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
       3 \\ 6 \\-3 \\ 5 \\  9\\ 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       3^2 + 6^2 + (-3)^2 + 5^2 +  9^2 + 2^2  \\
     \end{bmatrix} =[164] \]

   \[\textbf{aa}' = \begin{bmatrix}
       3 \\ 6 \\-3 \\ 5 \\  9\\ 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
       3 & 6 &-3 & 5 &  9& 2  \\
     \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
       3^2& 3\cdot 6 & 3\cdot (-3) & 3\cdot 5 &  3\cdot 9 & 3\cdot 2  \\
  6\cdot 3& 6^2 & 6\cdot (-3) & 6\cdot 5 &  6\cdot 9 & 6\cdot 2  \\
    (-3)\cdot 3& (-3)\cdot 6 & (-3)^2 & (-3)\cdot 5 &  (-3)\cdot 9 & (-3)\cdot 2  \\
      5\cdot 3& 5\cdot 6 & 5\cdot (-3) & 5^2 &  5\cdot 9 & 5\cdot 2  \\
        9\cdot 3& 9\cdot 6 & 9\cdot (-3) & 9\cdot 5 &  9^2 & 9\cdot 2  \\
         2\cdot 3& 2\cdot 6 & 2\cdot (-3) & 2\cdot 5 &  2\cdot 9 & 2^2  \\
     \end{bmatrix} \\=\begin{bmatrix}
       9& 18 & 9 & 15 &  27 & 6  \\
  18& 36 & -18 & 30 &  54 & 12  \\
    -9& -18 & 9 & -15 &  27 & -6  \\
      15& 30 & 15 & 10 &  45 & 10 \\
        27& 54 & 27 & 45 &  81 & 18  \\
         6& 12 & 6 & 10 &  18 & 4  \\
     \end{bmatrix} \]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `align*`

Comment: How exactly to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `eqnarray*` (ever) but `align*`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
   \mathbf{aa}' &= \begin{bmatrix}
                    3 \\ 6 \\-3 \\ 5 \\  9\\ 2  \\
                \end{bmatrix}\cdot
                \begin{bmatrix}
                  3 & 6 &-3 & 5 &  9& 2  \\
                \end{bmatrix}\\
             & = \begin{bmatrix}
                    3^2& 3\cdot 6 & 3\cdot (-3) & 3\cdot 5 &  3\cdot 9 & 3\cdot 2  \\
                    6\cdot 3& 6^2 & 6\cdot (-3) & 6\cdot 5 &  6\cdot 9 & 6\cdot 2  \\
                    (-3)\cdot 3& (-3)\cdot 6 & (-3)^2 & (-3)\cdot 5 &  (-3)\cdot 9 &
                    (-3)\cdot  2  \\
                    5\cdot 3& 5\cdot 6 & 5\cdot (-3) & 5^2 &  5\cdot 9 & 5\cdot 2  \\
                    9\cdot 3& 9\cdot 6 & 9\cdot (-3) & 9\cdot 5 &  9^2 & 9\cdot 2  \\
                    2\cdot 3& 2\cdot 6 & 2\cdot (-3) & 2\cdot 5 &  2\cdot 9 & 2^2  \\
                    \end{bmatrix} \\
             & =\begin{bmatrix}
                    9& 18 & 9 & 15 &  27 & 6  \\
                    18& 36 & -18 & 30 &  54 & 12  \\
                    -9& -18 & 9 & -15 &  27 & -6  \\
                    15& 30 & 15 & 10 &  45 & 10 \\
                    27& 54 & 27 & 45 &  81 & 18  \\
                    6& 12 & 6 & 10 &  18 & 4  \\
                \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want everything aligned to the left, use `flalign*`

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}       %%% remove showframe
\begin{document}
  \begin{flalign*}
   \mathbf{aa}' &= \begin{bmatrix}
                    3 \\ 6 \\-3 \\ 5 \\  9\\ 2  \\
                \end{bmatrix}\cdot
                \begin{bmatrix}
                  3 & 6 &-3 & 5 &  9& 2  \\
                \end{bmatrix}\\
             & = \begin{bmatrix}
                    3^2& 3\cdot 6 & 3\cdot (-3) & 3\cdot 5 &  3\cdot 9 & 3\cdot 2  \\
                    6\cdot 3& 6^2 & 6\cdot (-3) & 6\cdot 5 &  6\cdot 9 & 6\cdot 2  \\
                    (-3)\cdot 3& (-3)\cdot 6 & (-3)^2 & (-3)\cdot 5 &  (-3)\cdot 9 &
                    (-3)\cdot  2  \\
                    5\cdot 3& 5\cdot 6 & 5\cdot (-3) & 5^2 &  5\cdot 9 & 5\cdot 2  \\
                    9\cdot 3& 9\cdot 6 & 9\cdot (-3) & 9\cdot 5 &  9^2 & 9\cdot 2  \\
                    2\cdot 3& 2\cdot 6 & 2\cdot (-3) & 2\cdot 5 &  2\cdot 9 & 2^2  \\
                    \end{bmatrix} \\
             & =\begin{bmatrix}
                    9& 18 & 9 & 15 &  27 & 6  \\
                    18& 36 & -18 & 30 &  54 & 12  \\
                    -9& -18 & 9 & -15 &  27 & -6  \\
                    15& 30 & 15 & 10 &  45 & 10 \\
                    27& 54 & 27 & 45 &  81 & 18  \\
                    6& 12 & 6 & 10 &  18 & 4  \\
                \end{bmatrix}
                &        %%% this & is necessary
  \end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use eqnarray?

Comment: @Olga: Read the answers in: [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: @Harish Kumar:  One might also put the matrices in a `medsize` environment  (from `nccmath`, ~ 80 % of `\displaystyle`) in order to have more easy-to-read computations.

Comment: Thanks. How to make sure that the output is aligned on the left but not center as it is right now?

Comment: Then use the `flalign*` environment.

Comment: @Bernard yes, but I don't prefer it. :-)

Comment: @Olga Please see the update using `flalign*`.

Comment: That's strange. Didn't work for me.

Comment: @Olga Compile my second code as such. Does it work? You have to add `&` at the end.

Comment: It worked perfectly!